# For loop to print old value and sum of old value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using for loop in python to display old value and sum of new value. Following is my code.

```
numbers = [6, 5, 3, 8, 4, 2, 5, 4, 11]
sum = 0
for val in numbers:

    sum = sum+val
print(sum)
```

and the output of this loop is showing `48`

But i want to show output like

```
6
6+5 = 11
11+3 = 14
14+8 = 22
22+4 = 26
26+2 = 28
28+5 = 33
33+4 = 37
37+11 = 48
```

Please let me know what i need to change in my code to display output like this.

Comment: First thing first: Your print statement is outside the loop. This means it will only execute once.

Comment: @Anton vBR But when i print statement inside the loop then following error is showing :- 

        File "<module1>", line 5
            print(sum)
             ^
        IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Python forces you to use the correct indentation. Be careful that you have the right amount of spaces/tabs.

Comment: and dont mix spaces and tabs in python3.x

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just iterate through elements in list, printing the required in the loop and updating the `total`:

```
numbers = [6, 5, 3, 8, 4, 2, 5, 4, 11]

total = numbers[0]
print(f'{total}')
for val in numbers[1:]:
    print(f'{total} + {val} = {total + val}')
    total += val

# 6
# 6 + 5 = 11
# 11 + 3 = 14                                                 
# 14 + 8 = 22                                                 
# 22 + 4 = 26                                                 
# 26 + 2 = 28                                                
# 28 + 5 = 33                                                 
# 33 + 4 = 37                                                 
# 37 + 11 = 48
```

Comment: @Austin thanks its working. But one question in my mind. Please let me know what is use of f in print(f'{sum} + {val} = {sum + val}')?

Comment: @Ramona, They are f-strings in Python, just another way of formatting strings. You can specify variable in `{}` and Python will display it's value for you.